# One-To-One, Unidirectional Relationship

Tags: symfony, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I have these entities: - Store and Package

I'd like to build a StoreType form where i add package Id.

I've made a StoreType Form class: (I would expect to get a select box from this, where all package are listed)

I've add the package through one to one, but my problem is when i add package in store form then form is create but in my database store table column package are empty.i don't know why?

Store.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Store
     {
        /**
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         */
        protected $id;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="string", length="255")
         */
        protected $title;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="string", length="255")
         */
        protected $domain;

        /**
         * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Package",cascade={"persist", "remove"})
         * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="package_id", referencedColumnName="id")
         */
        protected $package;
    }
```

Package.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Package
     {
         /**
          * @ORM\Id
          * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
          * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
          */
         protected $id;

         /**
          * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
          */
         protected $title;

         /**
          * @ORM\Column(type="text", length="4000")
          */
         protected $description;

         /**
          * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
          */
         protected $active;


         public function __toString()
          {
           return $this->getTitle();
          }
     }
```

StoreType.php

```
class StoreType extends AbstractType
    {
        public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
        {
            $builder
                ->add('title')
                ->add('domain')
                ->add('package','entity',array(
                    'class' => 'WebmuchProductBundle:Package',
            ));
        }


        public function getName()
        {
            return 'webmuch_productbundle_storetype';
        }
    }
```

StoreController.php

```
/**
 * Store controller.
 *
 * @Route("/store")
 */
class StoreController extends Controller
{
/**
 * Lists all Store entities.
 *
 * @Route("/", name="store")
 * @Template()
 */
public function indexAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

    $entities = $em->getRepository('WebmuchProductBundle:Store')->findAll();

    return array('entities' => $entities);
}

/**
 * Finds and displays a Store entity.
 *
 * @Route("/{id}/show", name="store_show")
 * @Template()
 */
public function showAction($id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository('WebmuchProductBundle:Store')->find($id);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Store entity.');
    }

    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);

    return array(
        'entity'      => $entity,
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),        );
}

/**
 * Displays a form to create a new Store entity.
 *
 * @Route("/new", name="store_new")
 * @Template()
 */
public function newAction()
{
    $store = new Store();
    $form   = $this->createForm(new StoreType(), $store);

    return array(
        'entity' => $store,
        'form'   => $form->createView()
    );
}

/**
 * Creates a new Store entity.
 *
 * @Route("/create", name="store_create")
 * @Method("post")
 * @Template("WebmuchProductBundle:Store:new.html.twig")
 */
public function createAction()
{
    $entity  = new Store();
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $form    = $this->createForm(new StoreType(), $entity);
    $form->bindRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('store_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));

    }

    return array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView()
    );
}

/**
 * Displays a form to edit an existing Store entity.
 *
 * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="store_edit")
 * @Template()
 */
public function editAction($id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository('WebmuchProductBundle:Store')->find($id);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Store entity.');
    }

    $editForm = $this->createForm(new StoreType(), $entity);
    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);

    return array(
        'entity'      => $entity,
        'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    );
}

/**
 * Edits an existing Store entity.
 *
 * @Route("/{id}/update", name="store_update")
 * @Method("post")
 * @Template("WebmuchProductBundle:Store:edit.html.twig")
 */
public function updateAction($id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository('WebmuchProductBundle:Store')->find($id);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Store entity.');
    }

    $editForm   = $this->createForm(new StoreType(), $entity);
    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);

    $request = $this->getRequest();

    $editForm->bindRequest($request);

    if ($editForm->isValid()) {
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('store_edit', array('id' => $id)));
    }

    return array(
        'entity'      => $entity,
        'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    );
}

/**
 * Deletes a Store entity.
 *
 * @Route("/{id}/delete", name="store_delete")
 * @Method("post")
 */
public function deleteAction($id)
{
    $form = $this->createDeleteForm($id);
    $request = $this->getRequest();

    $form->bindRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $entity = $em->getRepository('WebmuchProductBundle:Store')->find($id);

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Store entity.');
        }

        $em->remove($entity);
        $em->flush();
    }

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('store'));
}

private function createDeleteForm($id)
{
    return $this->createFormBuilder(array('id' => $id))
        ->add('id', 'hidden')
        ->getForm()
    ;
}
}
```

Comment: Your code seems to be fine. Even I used your code and everything is ok for me (the difference is I've made public access to all properties to avoid necessity create getters/setters - but if you have getters/setters it should work fine as well). So I suggest you, check your setters/getters in entities and namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget to do this in your createAction  :

```
 $request = $this->getRequest();
$form->setData($request->getPost());
```

Comment: He has: $form->bindRequest($request); and doesn't need "setData"

Comment: so he has to see var_dump() for $request->getPost() and $form->getData()

Comment: Cyprian and Sina Miandashti thanks.I solved it.I just made set id of Store entity as a public.Then it worked. public function setId() { return $this->id; }